# Repeate Parent column in child table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, relational-database

I have following Three tables 
**Periods**

```
--------------------------------
ID StartDate   EndDate      Type
--------------------------------
1  2013-01-01   2013-01-01    D
2  2013-01-02   2013-01-02    D
```

**Attendance**

```
---------------------------------------------------
ID PeriodID   UploadedBy   uploadDateTime    Approved
--------------------------------------------------
1      1        25          2013-01-01-11:00   1
2      1        54          2013-01-01-10:00   1
```

**Attendance Detail**

```
---------------------------------------------
ID EmployeeID   AttendanceTime   Status AttendanceID
---------------------------------------------
1      24       2013-01-01 09:05  CheckIn   1
1      28       2013-01-01 09:08  CheckOut  2
```

Attendance data is filled through biomatric machined generated CSV files. `Attendancedetail` may group over time as there are multiple checkin out per employee per day. Attendance is approved  for each period `period`.

**Qustion**

I need attendance data per period basis. I know I can achieve this though `joins`. but i have to use `between` filter on AttendenceTime. I was thinking to add `PeriodID` in `AttendenceDetail`  table also to simplify queries and future performance issue. should I go for it or there is better solution available

Answer (score 0):

If you often need Attendance details based per Period, so you usually need to join the three tables but the Attendance data (from the Attendance table) are not so important for you then the PeriodID in the Attendance Detail table will help you for sure.

Even if you need all three tables, a where condition on PeriodID will narrow down the number of rows from Attendance Detail, so it will be again helpful in terms of performance.

Maybe it can be a bit annoying to maintain a not fully normalized schema, but if it's not a big hassle and this doesn't impact your writing performance go for the PeriodID in the Attendance Detail. Your selects will thank you :)

Comment: What about data integrity? He has to be sure he always updates them all together or there's a chance they can get out of sync.